# Git ls-remote and git update with Crowd authentication

Tags: git, jenkins, atlassian-crowd

I have switched my Git repos to authenticate with Crowd instead of basic authentication. It's all working great when anyone can authenticate, but I have problems with two commands, any ideas how to solve it?

1. git ls-remote -h  HEAD
   I do not have a way to specify any credentials here (it's in Jenkins)
2. git remote update 
   How to pass credentials here?

In Jenkins, when configuring Git repository URL I get following:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h http://---/---.git HEAD"  returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: fatal: Authentication failed
```

Comment: What Git repository manager are you using? You may be able to use SSH (for example [Enabling SSH access to Git repositories in Stash](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Enabling+SSH+access+to+Git+repositories+in+Stash)).

Comment: I access it via http, I do not have SSH and I do not want it enabled. So it's smart http setup on Apache, with Gitolite to manage permissions. Problems (well, mostly annoying message) started when I switched to Crowd for authentication.

Comment: Can you give examples of the messages? Crowd's Apache integration presents Basic Authentication to the client, so it shouldn't be different from before except for using the central Crowd credentials.

Comment: @Joe: In Jenkins it's the only message that I get.